# Hibernate: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to create one to one relationship in Jpa. When I run this program throw the Exception

```
ERROR: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ngsharma`.`student`, CONSTRAINT `FK8nqh8nm4hrwx9hlqwhxf6kfen` FOREIGN KEY (`laptop_lid`) REFERENCES `laptop` (`lid`))
```

**Student**

```
@Entity(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id 
    private  int rollno;
    private String name;    
    @OneToOne 
    private Laptop laptop;

    /*Setter & Getter*/
}
```

**Laptop**

```
@Entity(name = "laptop")
public class Laptop {

    @Id
    private int lid;
    private String laptopName;

    /*Setter & Getter*/
}
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ngsharma</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Run CLass**

```
    Configuration configuration = 
            new Configuration().configure()
                                                    .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class).addAnnotatedClass(Laptop.class);

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Laptop laptop = new Laptop();
    laptop.setLid(101);
    laptop.setLaptopName("Mac Nootbook");

    Student student = new Student();
    student.setRollno(1);
    student.setName("Shri Krishan");
    student.setLaptop(laptop);

     Serializable serializable = session.save(student);
     System.out.println("Test Code : "  + serializable);

     session.beginTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Where did you save the laptop object to the database? like you did with `Serializable serializable = session.save(student);`. To save student you need an existing laptop entity in your database and _then_ save your student

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are trying to save a `student` entity, for which `laptop` association does not exist in database. Both instances are newly created as far as understand from the code snippet you provided. Hence, according to the foreign constraint at database level, you are trying to reference `laptop` table from within `student` table; where the corresponding `laptop` row with the referenced `id` does not exist.

If you also persist the associated `laptop` entity while persisting the `student` entity your problem will be solved. The only modification you need to do is to update the `@OneToOne` relation as:

```
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)  
    private Laptop laptop;
```

This will work; since it will also insert the `laptop` entity to the database along with the `student` entity itself.